# Passing JS value to HTML to create anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables, slider, anchor

I am trying to get the year value to pass to the a tag, including the "#" so that I can then use the slider year value as a link to a div further down the page.

What do I need to change?

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("year");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

document.getElementById("year").href = year;
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="2009" max="2020" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

<a href="#" id="year">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting href to `year` which is not defined ( as I can see in your question ). You can just set your `output` href in `oninput` function. So, your code will look like this:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("year");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  output.href = '#' + this.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the value to the href property within the `oninput` event handler.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("year");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  output.href = '#' + this.value;
}
```

```css
/* Display the current 'href' value for demo */
a::after {
  content: 'href=' attr(href);
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="2009" max="2020" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

<a href="#" id="year">
</a>
```